# Wordpress data from database won't display in template

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I have a shrotcode and I want to display in the shortcode some data from database and I still get this(the sintax of php):[image]

Here is my code for the template :

```
    <?php global $wpdb;
    $table_name = $wpdb->prefix . 'property';
    $properties = $wpdb->get_results("SELECT * FROM $table_name");

    ?>

<?php foreach ($properties as $property) : ?>

    <div class="col-sm-4 my-4 card-selector">
        <div class="card bg-light text-dark card-height">
            <?php if ($property->sale_rent == 0) : ?>
                <div class="corner-ribbon top-left sticky red shadow">Sale</div>
            <?php elseif ($property->sale_rent == 1): ?>
                <div class="corner-ribbon top-left sticky red shadow">Rent</div>
            <?php endif; ?>
            <img class="img-responsive card-img-top" src="" alt="">
            <div class="card-body">
                <h2 class="card-title"><?php echo $property->country ?></h2>
                <h3 class="card-title"><?php echo $property->price ?> £</h3>
                <h5 class="card-title"><?php echo $property->county, $property->town ?></h5>
                <h6 class="card-title"><?php echo $property->displayable_address ?></h6>
                <i class="fas fa-bed"><?php echo $property->nr_of_bedrooms ?></i> <i
                        class="fas fa-bath"><?php echo $property->nr_of_bathrooms ?></i>
                <p id="description" class="description card-text"><?php echo $property->property_description ?></p>
                {% if property.custom %}
                <?php if ($property->custom) : ?>
                    <a href="" class="card-link">Edit</a>
                    <a class="deleterow card-link"
                       href="">Delete</a>
                <?php endif; ?>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Here i get the shortcode :

```
  <?php

function r_view_property_form_shortcode()
{

    $formHTML = file_get_contents('view-property-template.php', true);

    return $formHTML;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of using file_get_contents() try using include. Something like this.

```
ob_start();
include 'view-property-template.php';
$output = ob_get_clean();
return $output;
```